# uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've updated Android Studio last night to 0.9.0, buildToolsVersion to 21.1.0 and gradle to 0.14.0, after that I'm receiving this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute

I've spent the last night looking for a solution, I found this:

 `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />`

But unfortunately, added one more error!

> Error:(10, 5) uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute 
>   Error:(10, 5) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute

Another solution I've read, to not use support-v4:21, for me I don't use it, since I'm using v13.

Answer (score 19):

#### Solution:--

Add this line to uses-sdk tag like this:-

```
<uses-sdk
    tools:node="merge"   <----This line do the magic
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

And add the tools name space in manifest :-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" .....
.../>
```

Comment: adding xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" into manifest worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

OK this is not the answer, but a temporary workaround.

According to the Gradle build tools [release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) this problem was fixed in version 0.13.2 (2014/09/26)
However, seems to happen again in 0.14.0 (2014/10/31)

You can disable the manifest merger task in order to build your project for the time being.
Add the following in your `build.gradle` file

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.processResources.manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
variant.processManifest.enabled=false }
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937123/disable-manifest-merger-in-android-gradle-build) for reference.

Comment: I updated the IDE / gradle build tools on my other desktop, sync / build works perfectly.
I would appreciate any insight on the matter.

Comment: More insight: It appears that the ASNE library caused this issue, check out my comments at the [bug report](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE/issues/46)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this after upgrading to Android Studio 1.0.0 rc4.  I had previously been using  so that I could make projects with lower min SDK versions than some of the libraries they depended on.  Turns out, if you remove tools:replace and let the compiler error out again with the manifest merge conflict, it will provide you with a much better solution:

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms" />
```

At least, the Google Play Services library was what I was running into.  Actually, you can list a whole bunch if you need to.  Just comma-separate the package names.  You may have to run the compiler a few times until it tells you every library that's causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

My solution

- I have removed all of the `<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />`    From all of my manifest.xml files
- In my base.gradle file(the one for the entire project I Added

  ```
  ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 19
    buildToolsVersion = "21"
    minSdkVersion = 10
    targetSdkVersion = 19
  }
  ```
- In my modules I have this

  ```
  // all modules
  compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
  buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
  // in an application module
  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.something"
     minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
     targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
     versionCode appVersionCode
     versionName appVersionName
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>The problem has solved after updating the AS to v0.9.1 and Gradle to 0.14.1.</strike>

Thank you guys_

**Update**

The problem appears again!

**Update 2**

Here is a workaround to solve this problem:

1. Open your project with Android Studio 0.8.14 / Gradle build tools 0.13.2
2. Build your project.
3. Switch back to Android Studio 0.9.1 / Gradle build tools 0.14.1
4. gradlew assembleRelease will work now

Comment: I have AS 0.9.2, Gradle 0.14.1, and error still there.

Comment: Iaph a quick help, if you are using any external libraries (like in my case ASNE) make sure the manifest of these libraries do not have <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />