# Error: A problem was found with the configuration of task collectDebugMultiDexComponents

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I've update Android Studio to 0.9, build tools to 21.1.0 and gradle to 0.14 because I want to use the new multiDexEnabled true feature. Currently I'm managing the multidex using this approach  https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex and everything is working, but the multiDexEnabled feature seems better.

But using gradle 0.14 I've got this error : [uses-sdk element cannot have a "tools:node" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688711/uses-sdk-element-cannot-have-a-toolsnode-attribute) which I "solved" using the [solution posted by @Medo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26693092/4208269).

But if I use this approach the multiDexEnabled won't work , and I'll get this error:

Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':participactclient:collectDebugMultiDexComponents'.

File '/Users/danielecampogiani/Developing/Android/Android Studio/Participact Client/participactclient/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not exist.

How to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need the `tools:node="replace"`?

Comment: I'm not using tools:node="replace" in my code, but I'm using [ASNE](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE) which is using tools:node="replace".