# Manifest merger failed when using Recyclerview for lower SDK version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I can getting the following error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be different than version L declared in library .../com.android.support/recyclerview-v7/21.0.0-rc1/AndroidManifest.xml

Below is my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
    ...

}
```

Using

```
<uses-sdk
    tools:node="replace" />
```

does not work anymore.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688711/uses-sdk-element-cannot-have-a-toolsnode-attribute). The solution suggested place following code in `gradle.build`

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.processResources.manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
variant.processManifest.enabled=false }
```

But I get error

```
Error:(21, 0) Could not find property 'processResources' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@dac7b2d.
```

No matter where I place the code in `gradle.build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0-rc1'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
```

to use the production release versions of those libraries, instead of the L-only preview versions. They will work back to API Level 7.

Comment: I get `Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0`. Does this mean I need to update the SDK?

Comment: @paradite: It would appear that your "Android Repository" is out of date -- get the latest from your SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks. It works on lower SDK now after updating from SDK manager.

Comment: there are newer version btw:   `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'`
  `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'`