# Android studio Adds extra permissions to my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app which makes use of wifi permissions only but ever since I moved to android studio, the compiled apk of my app uses two more extra permissions, that is phone calls/phone id and SD read/write. 
I have no idea how and why those permissions have been added to my app but many users complain about that.
My app uses google analytics from google play services and appcompat. I also make use of this line

```
deviceId = Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Any ideas? I don't want those extra permissions they scare my users away

Here is the content of manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Comment: Post the content of your AndroidManifest.xml, please.

Comment: Hey @aga sorry for the omission I edited my post

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: Are you using the WifiManager in your project?

Comment: Are you using some libraries with these permissions? The manifest merger pulls in permissions from all modules you have in the project.

Comment: @Mondain Yes Iam using WifiManager I've always been using it

Comment: @laalto Only local libs I use is SmoothProgressbarLib which has no permissions in its manifest. The rest is appcompat and google play services latest versions

Answer (score 0):

Studio is adding permissions appropriate to the classes / features that you are using in your project.

**Update**
[Here is a related question that focuses on manifest merging config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13937123/127938)

Comment: Even if I don't add them manually at my manifest? Does this mean I can delete the permissions from my manifest and let android studio choose them automatically?

Comment: You can remove them but wifimanager for instance won't function without the right permissions.

Comment: I see. well if thats the case then that's bad cause my code used to work fine on eclipse with only the permissions writen on my manifest. Now I have to find which lines of my code trigger phone-Id-calls and SD card permissions So I see what to do next

Comment: I really dislike the manifest merging thing. I have the same issue of unwanted permissions. i would like to disable manifest merging. how can i do it?