# sms is verified without the permissions with sinch SDK in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using sinch SDK for user number verification, I want the user to manually enter the code he received so i didnt gave the required permissions in the manifest file for the `onVerificationFailed`
method to be fired, and then ask the user to enter the code he received. but even without the permissions the `onVerified` method fires.

**EDIT**

I now see in the application info on the phone that the required permissions are granted to the app even tough they are not added by me in the manifest, how do i solve this?

Comment: uninstall the app you probably asked for it n an earlier during your dev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962789/android-gradle-manifest-merger-override-uses-permission-attribute-coming-from

Comment: @cjensen i uninstalled it already, it still has it. i also cleaned the project after uninstalled it and before installing it again.