# Android build will not merge manifests from libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

We have multiple projects, depending on a many Android lib modules.
To avoid duplicated xml tags in the apps manifests, we put the relevant receivers, services and activities in their respective modules.

Till today, we used:

- Android Studio: 2.2.1
- gradle: 2.1.3
- buildToolsVersion: 23.0.3

Today we've updated to:

- Android Studio: 2.3
- gradle: 2.3.0
- buildToolsVersion: 25.0.0

Up until this update, everything worked just fine and the manifests were merged, we had conflicts and we fixed them. As of the update we've done, the manifests will not merge, at all!!

--- Update 1 ---

We've used the Merged Manifest view, and saw that it just doesn't include the manifests in the merge, the only thing it does merge from the modules manifest is the permissions, so for example, if I add a new permission to a modules manifest it would ONLY merge it and not the rest of the elements!

[image: Nothing to merge]

I guarantee there are a lot of stuff to merge!

--- Update 2 ---

It seems that everything **outside** the application tag it merges into the main manifest, and everything **within** the application tag, it doesn't.

--- Update 3 ---

**Module that doesn't merge:**

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':android-infra')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':engine-core-server')
    compile project(path: ':engine-core-aneeda')
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.sensiya.voip.managers.gcm"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.KAKI"/>


    <application
        tools:node="replace">
        <service
            android:enabled="true"
          android:name="com.sensiya.voip.managers.gcm.GcmIntentService"/>

        <receiver          android:name="com.sensiya.voip.managers.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>

                <category android:name="com.iamplus.onenumber.device"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Module that will merge:**

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(path: ':android-infra')
    compile 'com.sensiya:sense-services-client:1.24.2@aar'
    compile project(path: ':engine-core-server')
    compile project(path: ':engine-core-aneeda')
}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.iamplus.android.senseServices"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        tools:node="replace">
        <service
            android:name="com.iamplus.senseServices.ContextualEventService"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.iamplus.senseServices.Serv"
            android:enabled="true"/>

        <service
            android:name="com.iamplus.senseServices.Serv1"
            android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: No logs in console? No errors?

Comment: Asolutly nothing...

Comment: can you share your app gradle file.

Comment: not really it has a few dependencies files, anything specific I can provide?

Comment: Did you try doing a Gradle Clean and an android studio 'invalidate caches and restart'. If there was a previous conflict it could just be a caching issue

Comment: Yes cleaned, deleted build folder from all the modules...

Comment: It would be helpful if you just share bare project with no production code.

Comment: @TacB0sS check if your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml will be overridden by what you have mention in your build.gradle files....to me this happens usually with update sometimes...so you simply make changes their after that clean ,rebuild,sync...

Comment: _will not merge_ like there is an error; or like there is no error and no result either?

Comment: Can you try to create new project with same package name and move your files to the new project and also use recent build tool version 25.3.1, Android studio 2.3 has some bugs

Comment: @tynn There are no errors, and it just complete the "merge" process without merging any of the dependencies components into the final manifest

Comment: @TacB0sS, so you expect to see lets say activities elements from ModuleA's manifest merged to your app's manifest ? and its missing there .. right ?

Comment: Yes, and they are not there. ..

Comment: See my updated answer. I think your issue is with importing modules or its component not with merging. can you check if you can assess any resource in modules ?

Comment: It woild compile the project if it wouldn't... i can access strings and classes from all the unmeged modules

Answer (score 9):

It could be many things.Since  you didn't provide code, I will guess you are using default merge behavior. For more information, see: [Merge conflict heuristics](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_conflict_heuristics)

You can use [**Merged Manifest view**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) to preview the results of your merged manifest and find conflict errors.

In general, merge by default should work. Then just use **Merged Manifest view** to see how & where you lost values during merging. Using [Merge rule markers](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#merge_rule_markers) would help you to manage merge by assigning rules markers.

**If there is no merge at all. so it's probably a dependency issue between modules.**

Note that dependency order plays a crucial role with modules which have the same priority level, such as libraries.

**--- Update 5.April.2017 ---**

Here are some useful tips:

1. Try to update and rebuild other libs as much as you can.
2. Remove all dependencies and then clean project, then add them again. and
   check if you import them properly. that could be done by build the project without issues.
3. Note that since gradle 2.2.0 assets from modules won't be accessible
   in app.
4. Check you manifest if merge process is not disabled exciplicitly by attribute:
   `tools:node=”remove"` or `tools:node="removeAll"` or in gradle( see
   this [Disable Manifest Merger in Android Gradle Build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959122/2267723))
5. Try to create a demo with a module and track merging. and then match
   outputs to your projects. This will make it clear that is not
   configuration issue but Android Studio 2.3 ( so then re-install fresh
   version )

**--- Update(2) 5.April.2017 ---**

After you had added code, I could see that you are using Attribute

```
tools:node="replace"
```

Under application element in your modules (and probably in app's manifest too). I think that is the reason why you didn't get any manifest merged from imported modules merged to your app's manifest. See `tools:node="replace"` under [Node markers](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#node_markers).

> Replace the lower-priority element completely. That is, if there is a
>   matching element in the lower-priority manifest, ignore it and use
>   this element exactly as it appears in this manifest.

That means both modules above will never get any thing merged with manifest from:

- android-infra
- com.sensiya:sense-services-client:1.24.2
- engine-core-server
- engine-core-aneeda

**So get rid of that attribute and clean and rebuild modules. then rebuild whole project.**

Comment: This seems like the best way so far.. I was not aware of the Merged View... I'll check it soon and post back

Comment: 1. tried, nothing. 2. tried, nothing. 3. known. 4. doesn't exits. 5. this is not related to the studio version, this also happens when building from the command line from other computers using gradle... so???

Comment: the replace was added in attempt to fix the issue, it is irrelevant as one module with replace does merge and another doesn't. we tried creating another project showing the issue, we could not reproduce it. we tried removing all the flags from the application tag in all submodules, we could not get it to merge...  there is a bug hidden deep in the Android plugin, and we just can't place it

Comment: Thanks for the [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts). In my case AS showed AndroidManifest in merged view, but two bottom tabs (`Text` and `Merged Manifest`) disappeared. I reopened AS, it showed AndroidManifest in normal view.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting manifest merge conflicts you have two options.

1) find all the manifest files included in your project including the ones in libraries that you have as dependencies, and ensure there are no conflicting configurations.

or 2) add some merge resolution rules to your Manifests to dictate how each conflict should be resolved.

There is a great page on that here with many details.
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html

Comment: there are no conflicting, there are no gardle console error or warning messages, and only if I copy the components manually into the app manifest it actually adds them to the final manifest

Answer (score 0):

From **Android Studio**  
*Build ---> Clean project*  
**then** 
 
*Build --> Make Project*

This should help fix

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for Unity. I was able to solve it by going on the SDK Manager and removing the latest android api. Then I installed a slightly older api and it worked (API 21 or 22 I think)

[What the SDK Manager looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/she8q.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recently have same problem in my production code.
Having one libraries into app module exists also in other Gradle Dependency causes the duplicate entries.
We need to exclude such module or libraries from conflicted one.

For that we must know number of libraries used by a particular Gadle dependency.

**Consider a case where I using "bolts-android-1.2.0.jar" in my app gradle.
In same gradle I m using facebookSDK as below.**

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0')
```

**So I have to exclude "bolts-android" as below**

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    }
```

So how to know that facebookSDK uses "bolts-android"

**Here you can use plugin** [Android Method Count](http://www.methodscount.com)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is from using `tools:node="replace"` in the `application` element. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html#node_markers):

> ...if there is a matching element in the lower-priority manifest, ignore it and use this element exactly as it appears in this manifest.

What you actually want to use is `tools:node="merge"` which is the default behavior.

> Merge **all** attributes in this tag and **all nested elements** when there are no conflicts using the merge conflict heuristics. This is the default behavior for elements.

Comment: I wish I could test this... the code is not available for me anymore